# Error django.db.utils.OperationalError al hacer makemigrations

Tags: django, postgresql

estoy intentando conectar Django con PostgreSQL (que lo he instalado en una máquina virtual con Windows 10), pero cada vez que intento hacer el makemigrations me tira el error del título (django.db.utils.OperationalError). En la máquina está el firewall desactivado (ya que si no me tira error), en modo puente, con detección de redes, ... Puedo hacer ping, así que conexión entre ellas hay... No sé dónde estará el fallo... Si me podéis echar una manilla... Os lo agradecería muchísimo.

La versión de Django es la 3.0.5 y la de Python 3.8.2, aunque he probado con la 3.7.7 también y el error sigue saliendo.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Clientes(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
direccion = models.CharField(max_length=50)
email = models.EmailField()
telefono = models.CharField(max_length=7)


class Articulos(models.Model):
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
seccion = models.CharField(max_length=20)
precio = models.IntegerField()


class Pedidos(models.Model):
numero = models.IntegerField()
fecha = models.DateField()
entregado = models.BooleanField()
```

settings.py:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'gestionPedidos', # añadido
'django.contrib.sites', # añadido
]

 MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]

 ROOT_URLCONF = 'TiendaOnline.urls'

 TEMPLATES = [
 {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'TiendaOnline.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'articulosclientes',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'root',
    'HOST': '192.168.1.49',
    'DATABASE_PORT': '5432',
}
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: puedes revisar si el nombre de la BBDD es correcto.

Answer (score 1):

podría ser un error de escritura en la parte de DATABASES del archivo settings.py, específicamente en el host. Al trabajar con postgresql el host debería ser: 127.0.0.1

Escrito quedarías así:

```
'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
```

O podrías escribirlo como 'localhost' así:

```
'HOST': 'localhost',
```

Posteriormente, ya podrías ejecutar en el terminal la siguiente linea

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Y finalmente para ver los resultados en postgresql, ejecuta en el terminal

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql'
```

esta mal, es

```
'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'
```

ademas de poner

```
'HOST':'localhost'
```